# String concatenation in stringtemplate

Tags: stringtemplate

I'm trying to make a lookup to a hash table `m.notes` using concatenated value of `position.qid` and literal `".qid"` like this:

```
$tag(name="itemId", content=m.notes.(position.qid".qid").itemId)$
```

I tried different options, but I get runtime error. Can someone correct my syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Put the 2 items in an array. StringTemplate concatenates all items in an array (or as they call it, a multi-valued-attribute) when it executes a ToString() on it.

`[position.qid, ".qid"]`

So, if position.qid evaluates to "hello", this expression would become
`hello.qid`.

Comment: This is correct, although it's not easy to understand. It all happens inside the ST-Template. The answer to the question would be like this: `$tag(name="itemId", content=m.notes.([position.qid,".qid"]).itemId)$`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether such concatenation is possible in string template. Why don't you use a different method that could do the concatenation and return the value.

e.g:
`position.fullQid` instead of `position.qid`

where,

```
public String getFullQid(){
return getQid() + ".qid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in template group, I can do like this, first, define a concantenate template:
    concantenate(substr)::=""
then use as following
    (concantenate([position.qid,".qid"]))